# topViewController error (iOS7 - works on iOS8)

Tags: objective-c, ios7, ios8

While doing some tests on my old iPhone 4 (iOS 7.1.2) I encountered an error performing a segue from my initial collectionView to a tableView.

Everything works fine on iOS 8, but I get the following error on iOS 7:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ListaPlatosTableViewController topViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17df3c70'**

My prepareForSegue method is the following:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

UINavigationController *nav = [segue destinationViewController];
ListaPlatosTableViewController *listaPlatosVC = (ListaPlatosTableViewController *)nav.topViewController;
[listaPlatosVC setPlatosCarta:platosCarta];

//I have set selectedCell in the method where I call performSegueWithIdentifier
[[[segue destinationViewController]topViewController]setTitle:selectedCell];

}
```

//UPDATE:
Here's the code that calls the segue, in case I'm overlooking something

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
selectedCell = [tiposCarta objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[self ponerPlatosEnCarta]; // I prepare platosCarta with this method
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ListaPlatos" sender:self];
}
```

has anyone encountered this?

Comment: iOS7 & 8 are both using the same storyboard, and this is for exactly the same test (so the same segue)?

Comment: Can you check if nav is type of ListaPlatosTableViewController. I think it is a UINavigationController, or ListaPlatosTableViewController doesn't have a property called topViewController.

Comment: @Wain - I'm testing the exact same code on both devices, selecting the same collection view cell and it works on one while failing on the other...

Comment: `topViewController` is a property of a navigation controller, not a table view controller, so the segue should point to a navigation controller for your code to work. If the same storyboard is used then the code should work or fail in both cases, you need to debug in both cases to see what's happening.

Comment: topViewController is a property to any subclass of UINavigationController only. So you cannot use it with UITableViewController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:
Perform the segues programmatically, not using the control-click in storyboard.
I don't know if I did something wrong with storyboard or if it is a bug with Xcode-ios7 (as it works fine for iOS8)
Any how, what i did was:

Disconnect the views that were giving problems in Storyboard, and prepare + launch them from the following methods:

my custom tableview launched from the collectionView:

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
selectedCell = [tiposCarta objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[self ponerPlatosEnCarta];
ListaPlatosTableViewController *listaPlatosVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"listaPlatosVC"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:listaPlatosVC animated:YES];
[listaPlatosVC setPlatosCarta:platosCarta];
[listaPlatosVC setTitle:selectedCell];
}
```

the "detail" view launched from the tableView:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

 PlatoHormigueroViewController *dvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detail"];
 dvc.elPlato = [self.platosCarta objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvc animated:YES];

}
```

This way it works the same on iOS 7 as 8.

Thanks everyone who replied in this thread for your time! :)

Answer (score 2):

[`topViewController`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ue5bz.jpg) is a property of `UINavigationController`.

here's the problem:[image]
Then have a segue to `ListaPlatosTableViewController`. Your code should look like:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    ListaPlatosTableViewController *listaPlatosVC = (ListaPlatosTableViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;

    listaPlatosVC.platosCarta = platosCarta;
    listaPlatosVC.title = selectedCell;
}
```

Comment: That indeed simplifies my code, but I am still getting the same error on iOS7... both in simulator as on my device... Thanks for the tip anyhow! :)

Comment: is your `ListaPlatosTableViewController` embedded in a navigation controller, and the segue is pointing to that navigation controller? or is it directly pointing to the `ListaPlatosTableViewController` ? Could you please upload a screenshot of your interface builder?

Comment: here's the screenshot: http://s17.postimg.org/v3vfw3atb/Screen_Shot_2015_01_25_at_20_39_34.png

Comment: You have to remove the second navigation controller. You already have a navigation controller, so both your viewControllers are embedded in the initial navigationController. So, remove the middle navigationController, and make the segue point to the `ListaPlatosTableViewController` directly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed my custom tableview now loads, but I do not have the navigation controller on top (don't have the option to go "Back" to the CollectionView), am I missing something or was my initial idea correct if I wanted to be able to go back?

Comment: To show/hide the navigation bar you can call `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];`

Comment: when calling [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES]; nothing happens if I remove the second navigation controller... it is as if the table view is not embedded in the initial navigationController... I will continue working on this tomorrow, as I might just be missing a simple detail... Thanks once more for your tips, will mark your answer correct as soon as I get it working with your help

Comment: Check your interface builder as well to see if it's disabled somewhere there in the previous view controllers.